# how to hide all the divs under a div class and show a div of the same class in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div class named "subproperties". In that div, I have many div elements like border,background,logo,button. These div elements are hidden initially(using style="display:none;")

I also have a drop down box with these div element names as options. When I click an option say 'logo', that div is showed. Next when I click the option 'border', the 'logo' div should be hidden and the 'border' div should be shown. Similarly for all cases.

That is, I want all the divs of the class subproperties to be hidden and show only one. how to do that in jquery?

Here is my code.

```
 $("#properties option").click(function(){
        selectedOption=$(this).attr("value");

        switch(selectedOption){
            case '1':
                $("#borders").show();
                break;

            case '2':
                $("#backgrounds").show();
                break;

            case '3':
                $("#typography").show();
                break;
        }
    });

 <div class="float_left spaceleft" id="properties">
<p class="title1">Properties</p>
    <div class="seperator"></div>
        <select id="propertiesMenu" class="select" size="7">
                <option value="1">Borders</option>
                <option value="2">Backgrounds</option>
                <option value="3">Typography</option>

        </select>
</div><!--End of properties -->

 <div class="subproperties">

     <div class="float_left spaceleft" id="backgrounds" style="display:none;">
        <p class="title1">Backgrounds</p>
        <select id="backgroundsMenu" class="select" size="7">
            <option value="bgHtml">Wallpaper</option>
            <option value="bgForm">Form</option>
            <option value="bgInstruct">Instructions</option>
        </select>
      </div><!--End of backgrounds -->

      <div class="float_left spaceleft" id="typography" style="display:none;">
        <p class="title1">Typography</p>
        <div class="seperator"></div>
        <select id="typographyMenu" class="select" size="7">
            <option value="ftFormTitle">Title</option>
            <option value="ftFormDescription">Description</option>
            <option value="ftFieldTitle">Field Title</option>
            <option value="ftFieldText">Field Text</option>
        </select>
        </div><!--End of typography -->

     <div float_left spaceleft" id="borders" style="display:none;">
        <p class="title1">Borders</p>
        <select id="bordersMenu" class="select" size="7">
            <option value="brForm">Form</option>
            <option value="brDivider">Sections</option>
        </select>
        </div><!--End of borders -->

</div><!-- End of sub properties -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#properties option').click(function() { 
    $('.subproperties div').hide();
    //... switch statement ...
```

Comment: It can give strange results when using animations I think. First you hide everything and then you show one element again.

Comment: True for animations. But for hide() and show() this works well.

Answer (score 3):

To adjust in each case:

```
$('#subproperties').children(':not(#idofelementtoshow)').hide();

$('#subproperties').children('#idofelementtoshow').show();
```

Edit:
Maybe more elegant (id is id of element to show):

```
$('#id').show().siblings().hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
$("div.subproperties div").hide();
```

to hide all divs. Then use the selected div's id to show it:

```
$("#divid").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you show one, you want to hide the others, so something like:

```
 case '1':                                
      $("#borders").show();    
      $("#backgrounds").hide();
      $("#typography").hide();
      break;
```

Or you may wish to hide them all before the switch and then show the one specified.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it by hand, you can try the other answers.

Or you can take a look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) which offers a pretty good [Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/), which looks like what you want after all.

Answer (score 0):

get selected text from option and use these two lines:

<strike>var txt=...//GET TEXT FROM SELECT LIST</strike>

$("div.subproperties").hide();//HIDE ALL DIVS

$("div#"+txt).parents("div.subproperties").show();

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#propertiesMenu").change(function(){
        var txt=$("#propertiesMenu option:selected").text();
        $("div. subproperties").hide();
        $("div#"+txt).parents("div. subproperties").show();
    });
});
</script>
```